# Jquery Infinite Loop not working

Tags: jquery

I've 3 divs that i want to highlight (with a css class) one after each other.After that the loop restarts and should do the same thing. But it isn't working.

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gamito/6M65S/

This must be something obvious ...

```
<script>
$('.ticker').each(function(i) {
var elem = $(this);
var prev = $(this).prev();
setTimeout(function() {
    elem.addClass("selected");
    prev.removeClass("selected");
}, i * 2000);
});​
</script>
```

Comment: I think you'd want to use `setInterval` instead. Plus I think the logic is missing something. How do you know when it reaches the end? Why use `each()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Ktash answer, here's a streamlined version:

```
// Setup an interval timer
setInterval(function () {
    var next = $('.ticker.selected').removeClass('selected').next('.ticker').addClass('selected');
    if(!next.length) {
        $('.ticker:first').addClass('selected');
    }
}, 2000);
// Initialize the selected class
$('.ticker:first').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Reworked your code. New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AkPmw/).

Basically, you want to switch around your thinking. Set up an interval, and change it on the interval, not on offsets on the `setTimeout`. Otherwise you would need to do `setInterval` in a `setTimeout` to make sure they were spaced evenly.

New Code:

```js
// Setup an interval timer
setInterval(function () {
    // Get currently selected element
    var select = $('.ticker.selected');
    // Remove the class
    select.removeClass('selected');
    if(select.next('.ticker').length > 0) {
        // If we have more to go, select the next one
        select.next().addClass('selected');
    } else {
        // Otherwise restart
        $('.ticker').eq(0).addClass('selected');
    }
}, 2000);
// Initialize the selected class
$('.ticker').eq(0).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

You an do something like, http://jsfiddle.net/6M65S/13/

```
var play = function(){
    var $ticker = $('.ticker'),
        $curTicker = $('.ticker').filter('.selected');
    $ticker.removeClass('selected');
    if(!$curTicker.is(':last')) {
        $curTicker.next().addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $ticker.first().addClass('selected');
    }   
};
setInterval(play, 1000);
```